# Building different types of Highcharts Programmatically.

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

What I would like to do is to be able to render graphs dynamically giving defined set of parameters from a url. for example http://example.html?team=team1%chartype=pie.

This is my code for a simple 'column' http://jsfiddle.net/4mBWg/
This is my code for a simple 'pie' http://jsfiddle.net/YFdKt/

```
Code block (SO is not letting me post without code)
```

programmatically what would I need is to be able to accept a 'type' parameter example (pie, chart, line) and be able to plot the graph.

Simply changing the "type" is not sufficient. Looking at the two types of graphs I am assuming the plotOptions needs to be build dynamically...what would I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is only `html` then try,

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/3855394/1817690
var qs = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        var p=a[i].split('=');
        if (p.length != 2) continue;
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));

if(qs['type']) && qs['type']=='pie') {
    Pie chart js code goes here
}  else if(qs['type'] && qs['type']=='line') {
    Line chart js code goes here
}
```

If you are using `PHP` the you can do this like,

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='pie') { ?>
    Pie chart js code goes here
<?php }  else if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='line') { ?>
    Line chart js code goes here
<?php } ?>
```